# Как запустить mysqlcheck для БД в контейнере Docker?

Tags: docker

Как запустить mysqlcheck для БД в контейнере Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто запустить `mysqlcheck` и получить вывод:

```
docker exec <CONTAINER_NAME> mysqlcheck
```

Если нужно выполнить какие-то другие действия в контейнере, то можно сначала запустить `bash`:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash
```

А уже внутри контейнера:

```
root@6bc40d4c67ab:/# mysqlcheck
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_NAME> bash mysqlcheck
```

Comment: docker exec -it 524848eb0720 bash mysqlcheck - выполняю

/usr/bin/mysqlcheck: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck: cannot execute binary file - получаю ошибку